# Benefits of session regenerate?

Tags: php

I am currently using sessions to handle users data, for example:

- Username
- Password
- Name
- Permission

The thing I am wondering about is, if the data is encrypted before sent to session, would regenerate be pointless? I currently have it setup to delete old session from TMP and create a new one.

Could someone explain how it may benefit me I find with documentation they like to make features seem so important, much help appreciated! :)

Comment: Why are you changing session identifiers, or manually deleting sessions, ever, in the first place? PHP handles this on its own just fine...

Comment: @Dan Grossman I was told that it added extra security, but if you could explain the purpose that would be great. :)

Comment: It's kind of like asking the benefits of eating... you just have to eat or you'll die, you know?

Comment: it is not extra security, it is extra paranoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) does not actually prevent session fixation. However, it should be called, at the very least, when a user logs in to prevent the "generic" session fixation attack ([1](http://shiflett.org/articles/session-fixation), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)) from working.

1. The attacker includes a `PHPSESSID=` parameter in a URL he sends to the user, setting ("fixating") the browser's session ID to a known value. Or he could set a session cookie from one of your other subdomains (possible by uploading an HTML file with embedded JavaScript, for example).
2. He waits until the user logs in under that session.
3. He uses the known session ID to hijack the user's account.

Calling `session_regenerate_id()` prevents step 3 from succeeding, because the attacker would no longer know the session ID at that point.

Also, because subdomains can set cookies for parent domains (which are sent to other subdomains as well), it is recommended that you host any untrusted content on an entirely separate domain name in a well-known [TLD](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) such as `.com`, `.net`, or `.org`. Browsers contain blacklists (such as the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/)) that prevent setting cookies for these TLDs.

For example, content at `exampleusercontent.com` cannot set a cookie that would be sent to `example.com`.