# Reason to Randomly Regenerate Session ID?

Tags: php, session

Is this good practice? I've never seen it done before but it works well so far.

```
if(mt_rand(1, 10) == 1) {     # regenerate "randomly" on 10% of requests
    session_regenerate_id();
}
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: Why are you doing it on a 10% basis?

Comment: @Shredder To add what is hopefully an extra layer of security. I could be wrong, hence the question.

Comment: Why not just do it every time though?

Comment: According a guy on an online forum, it's bad practice. Then again, he could be wrong too.

Comment: Could you post the link to this in your question?

Comment: It "works well so far" should be "sessions don't break"; to me "well" implies that it does something advantageous ..

Comment: perhaps related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929524/benefits-of-session-regenerate , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461835/is-regenerating-the-session-id-after-successful-login-sufficient-to-prevent-sess?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134501/regenerating-session-id?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for whatever proper reason or context you would regenerate the session ID, you should do it every time, not just sometimes randomly (in your case a 10% basis). I don't see how doing it every time is bad practice (correct me if I'm wrong, I'd be curious as why). If someone has hacked a session, then regenerating the ID will cause "hacker" to lose their hacked session. If you only regenerate the ID 10% of the time, then there is a 90% chance they will still maintain their hacked session. No beuno.